# Why does this image look different in Photoshop and Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, colors, photoshop, color-profile

I have saved the image below using an embedded sRGB profile. Photoshop is set up with the proper color settings (RGB is sRGB IEc61966-2.1) and proof setup is "Internet Standard RGB (sRGB)". The image looks the same in Photoshop, Safari, and Firefox. But viewing it in Chrome 23 gives me a very dull image as if its not reading the embedded color profile.

Pages such as [this](http://www.petapixel.com/2012/06/25/is-your-browser-color-managed/) suggest that Chrome is properly managing color profiles. So am I doing something wrong here? Is it possibly a bug in how Chrome is handling color profiles? I have seen Chrome do some weird stuff (color profiles being obeyed and ignored back and forth as I scroll) in previous versions.

[image: Sample sRGB image]

Comment: Could you generalize that is a Google Chrome issue? Or maybe there are some settings? I say this because you said that in Safari it seems right, but Chrome and Safari are based in WebKit. One specific version or plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the colour profile, and then saving out the image again following the guidelines from [this guy »](http://viget.com/inspire/the-mysterious-save-for-web-color-shift)

Unfortunately you might have to fiddle around with your image once the colour profile's been stripped out but at least then you'll have a clean slate.

Answer (score -3):

Use # color code. it works better than R,G,B and...